# trigger y tabla mutante

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de actualizar las filas de una tabla debido a un trigger necesario que tengo. El error es el de las tablas mutantes y no se cómo modificar mi trigger para que no ocurra.

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE CITAS (
    OID_CITA NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
    HORA VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL, 
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL, 
    OID_CLINICA NUMBER, 
    USUARIO_MEDICO VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL, 
    USUARIO_RECEPCIONISTA VARCHAR2(75), 
    DNI_PACIENTE CHAR(9), 
    FOREIGN KEY(OID_CLINICA) REFERENCES CLINICAS(OID_CLINICA), 
    FOREIGN KEY(USUARIO_MEDICO) REFERENCES MEDICOS(USUARIO), 
    FOREIGN KEY(USUARIO_RECEPCIONISTA) 
    REFERENCES RECEPCIONISTAS(USUARIO), 
    FOREIGN KEY(DNI_PACIENTE) REFERENCES PACIENTES(DNI)
);
```

**El error**

> Se ha producido un error al guardar los cambios en la tabla "JHO"."CITAS": Fila 231: ORA-04091: table JHO.CITAS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA", line 7 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA'

**El trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CITA_IDENTICA
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF USUARIO_MEDICO,FECHA,HORA ON CITAS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_MEDICO VARCHAR(40) := :NEW.USUARIO_MEDICO;
  V_FECHA DATE := :NEW.FECHA;
  V_HORA VARCHAR2(20) := :NEW.HORA;
  V_CUENTA NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_CUENTA FROM CITAS WHERE USUARIO_MEDICO = V_MEDICO 
AND FECHA = V_FECHA AND HORA = V_HORA;
  IF V_CUENTA > 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'No puede haber más de una cita de un 
mismo médico para una fecha y una hora específica');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: ¿Qué son **Tablas mutantes**? ¿Podrías especificar que error aparece y mostrar la estructura de la tabla *CITAS*? así podemos  entender mejor el problema y de esa manera ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Es un error relacionado a la hora de actualizar algo de la tabla que el trigger no ve los datos actualizados. Dejo el error:Se ha producido un error al guardar los cambios en la tabla "JHO"."CITAS":
Fila 231: ORA-04091: table JHO.CITAS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA'

Comment: Entiendo, mas o menos ya tengo idea de que pueda ser pero sin la estructura no puedo confirmarlo ¿podrías colocar el create table de citas para hacer algunas pruebas?

Comment: CREATE TABLE CITAS
  (OID_CITA NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  HORA VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
  OID_CLINICA NUMBER,
  USUARIO_MEDICO VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL,
  USUARIO_RECEPCIONISTA VARCHAR2(75),
  DNI_PACIENTE CHAR(9),
  FOREIGN KEY(OID_CLINICA) REFERENCES CLINICAS(OID_CLINICA),
  FOREIGN KEY(USUARIO_MEDICO) REFERENCES MEDICOS(USUARIO),
  FOREIGN KEY(USUARIO_RECEPCIONISTA) REFERENCES RECEPCIONISTAS(USUARIO),
  FOREIGN KEY(DNI_PACIENTE) REFERENCES PACIENTES(DNI));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente error aparece porque el trigger está ejecutando una consulta a la misma tabla que la disparó.

> Se ha producido un error al guardar los cambios en la tabla "JHO"."CITAS": Fila 231: ORA-04091: table JHO.CITAS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA", line 7 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA'

**SOLUCIÓN 1 - UTILIZAR [TRANSACCIONES AUTÓNOMAS](https://dosideas.com/wiki/Transacciones_Autonomas_En_Oracle)**

> Las transacciones autonomas son transacciones que aunque son llamadas dentro de otra transaccion, sus acciones son independientes de la transaccion principal.

**Comprobamos como está actualmente la tabla:**

```
select * from citas;

  OID_CITA HORA  FECHA       OID_CLINICA USUARIO_MEDICO   USUARIO_RECEPCIONISTA   DNI_PACIENTE
---------- ----- ----------- ----------- --------------   ---------------------   ------------
         1 07:35 05/08/2017            1 1                1                       1234
         2 07:50 05/08/2017            1 1                1                       1234
         3 08:00 05/08/2017            1 1                1                       1222
```

**Creamos el trigger.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CITA_IDENTICA
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF USUARIO_MEDICO,FECHA,HORA ON CITAS
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  V_MEDICO VARCHAR(40) := :NEW.USUARIO_MEDICO;
  V_FECHA DATE := :NEW.FECHA;
  V_HORA VARCHAR2(20) := :NEW.HORA;
  V_CUENTA NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_CUENTA FROM CITAS WHERE USUARIO_MEDICO = V_MEDICO 
    AND FECHA = V_FECHA AND HORA = V_HORA;

  IF V_CUENTA > 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'No puede haber más de una cita de un 
    mismo médico para una fecha y una hora específica');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Lanzamos el UPDATE:**

```
SQL> update citas set hora = '07:36' where oid_cita = 1;

1 row updated
```

**Lanzamos otro UPDATE** que choque con la hora de otro registro:

```
SQL> update citas set hora = '07:50' where oid_cita = 1;
```

Ahora vemos el siguiente error que es el que deseamos que salga:

> update citas set hora = '07:50' where oid_cita = 1
>       ORA-20004: No puede haber más de una cita de un
>           mismo médico para una fecha y una hora específica
>       ORA-06512: en "JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA", línea 14
>       ORA-04088: error durante la ejecución del disparador 'JHO.TR_CITA_IDENTICA'

Esta solución solo es efectiva cuando actualices un registro por vez ya que si utilizas alguna forma de actualizar varios registros al mismo tiempo puede que no haga la validación.

**SOLUCIÓN 2 - VALIDAR DESDE LA APLICACIÓN**

Si estas trabajando a nivel de una aplicación lo recomendable en este caso es que hagas la validación desde el programa, así evitas consultar la misma tabla desde el trigger.