# Ayuda con Error SQL: ORA-04091: table X is mutating (trigger y tabla mutante)

Tags: plsql, trigger, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo que realizar un trigger que impida insertar un empleado en un departamento que tenga 7 o más empleados y que impida actualizar el departamento de un empleado a un departamento que ya tiene 7 o más empleados. Mi solución en principio era esta (**la solución ha de ser sin utilizar transacciones autónomas**):

```
create or replace trigger tr_ej02
before
  insert or update on employee
  for each row
declare
  num_emple integer;  
begin
  select count(*) into num_emple
  from employee
  where department_id = :new.department_id
  group by department_id;

if updating then
  if (num_emple >= 7) then
    raise_application_error(-20355, 'ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR, EN ESE DEPARTAMENTO YA HAY 7 O MÁS EMPLEADOS');
  end if;
end if;

if inserting then
  if (num_emple >= 7) then
    raise_application_error(-20355, 'ERROR AL INSERTAR, EN ESE DEPARTAMENTO YA HAY 7 O MÁS EMPLEADOS');
  end if;
end if;   

end tr_ej02;
/
```

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

```
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-04091: table EMPLE.EMPLOYEE is mutating, trigger/function may 
not see it
ORA-06512: at "EMPLE.TR_EJ02", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EMPLE.TR_EJ02'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Llevo toda la mañana y parte de la noche de ayer intentando ver el fallo, pero no lo consigo, así que al final tengo que pediros ayuda, a ver si me podéis echar una mano jeje... -.-'

He estado leyendo otras preguntas muy similares, pero nada... por ejemplo [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93011/trigger-y-tabla-mutante), que es bastante similar.

Un saludo a todos y muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En qué base de datos es? no tiene sentido que uses etiquetas mysql y oracle. Por favor edita la pregunta, elimina la etiqueta que no corresponde y con gusto te ayudamos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema cuando se choca con este error está en que no se está considerando el posible problema de concurrencia que puede surgir de este diseño. El select no es bloqueante y el trigger es before insert or update, así que dos usuarios podrían ver lo mismo e insertar.

La solución es implementar esta restricción de otra forma. Digamos, llevar el conteo  de los empleados por departamento en otra tabla y cotejar este valor antes de insertar, usando una estrategia que tenga en cuenta la transaccionalidad para editarlo (que si algo falla, todo se reverse, que si todo es exitoso, la actualización del conteo se haga siempre).

Esta respuesta usa como referencia [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866)