# Como abrir un cursor en un disparador en caso de if updating then

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, cursor

Tengo un disparador en una base de datos Oracle armado de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TELEPHONE_UD
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    OF area_code, telephone_number, extention, telephone_type, address_type, line_state, country_code  
  ON TELEPHONE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   .
   .
   ln_telephone_count        NUMBER;
   .
   .
   CURSOR cursor_telephone_count IS 
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     INTO ln_telephone_count 
     FROM TELEPHONE t 
     WHERE t.telephone_number = :NEW.telephone_number 
     AND t.identity_code= :NEW.identity_code 
     AND t.customer_id = :NEW.customer_id;
   .
   .
BEGIN
   IF DELETING  THEN
     .
     .
     .
   ELSE
      OPEN cursor_telephone_count;
      FETCH cursor_telephone_count INTO ln_telephone_count;
      .
      .
      .
      .
       IF updating  AND ((:OLD.area_code <> :NEW.area_code) OR
         (:OLD.telephone_number <> :NEW.telephone_number) OR
         (:OLD.extention <> :NEW.extention) OR
         (:OLD.telephone_type <> :NEW.telephone_type) OR
         (:OLD.address_type <> :NEW.address_type) OR
         (:OLD.line_state <> :NEW.line_state) OR
         (:OLD.country_code <> :NEW.country_code)) THEN
         .
         .
         .
         IF ((:OLD.line_state <> :NEW.line_state) AND
            (ln_telephone_count >= 1) AND
           (:NEW.line_state='OK')) THEN
            :NEW.line_state := 'INVALID';
            
         END IF;
      END IF;
      IF inserting THEN
         IF (lv_profile NOT IN ('DEFAULT', 'OPERATIVE') 
              OR lv_profile IS NULL) THEN
            :NEW.update_from := 'O';
         ELSE
            :NEW.update_from := 'B';
         END IF;
         IF (ln_telephone_count >= 1) AND 
            (:NEW.line_state='OK') THEN
            :NEW.line_state := 'INVALID';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      .
      .
      .   
END;
```

*los puntos son mas líneas de código,Las obvie al no ser relevantes, aclaro que no hay error de ejecución.*

Básicamente si existe uno o mas de un registro en teléfono con **line_state='OK'** el debería antes de insertar y actualizar igualarlo a **line_state='invalid'**.
Me funciona antes de insertar, es decir actualiza el estado a invalido si pongo ok, pero al actualizar no lo hace, y en base me quedan dos teléfonos en estado ok. Estoy realizando la validación mal?.

---

He realizado pruebas y me doy cuenta que al hacer un update si tomo un cursor no me entra a las validaciones de abajo ponga lo que ponga.

```
IF updating  AND ((:OLD.area_code <> :NEW.area_code) OR
         (:OLD.telephone_number <> :NEW.telephone_number) OR
         (:OLD.extention <> :NEW.extention) OR
         (:OLD.telephone_type <> :NEW.telephone_type) OR
         (:OLD.address_type <> :NEW.address_type) OR
         (:OLD.line_state <> :NEW.line_state) OR
         (:OLD.country_code <> :NEW.country_code)) THEN
         
         IF (lv_profile NOT IN ('DEFAULT', 'OPERATIVE')
             OR lv_profile IS NULL) THEN
             :NEW.update_from := 'O';
         ELSE
             :NEW.update_from := 'B';


 
   
         END IF;
         --OPEN cursor_telephone_count_update;
         --FETCH cursor_telephone_count_update INTO ln_telephone_count_update;
         --CLOSE cursor_telephone_count_update;
         IF --(ln_telephone_count_update >= 1) AND 
           (:NEW.line_state='OK') THEN
           :NEW.line_state := 'INVALID';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
      IF inserting THEN
        OPEN cursor_telephone_count;
        FETCH cursor_telephone_count INTO ln_telephone_count;
        CLOSE cursor_telephone_count;
        IF (ln_telephone_count >= 1) AND 
          (:NEW.line_state='OK') THEN
          :NEW.line_state := 'INVALID';
        END IF;
         IF (lv_profile NOT IN ('DEFAULT', 'OPERATIVE') 
              OR lv_profile IS NULL) THEN
            :NEW.update_from := 'O';
         ELSE
            :NEW.update_from := 'B';
         END IF;
      END IF;
```

Si las lineas en if updating las desdocumento, nunca entra a la validacion de abajo, cosa que si entra si no hago el proceso de abrir el cursor.
el query del cursor_telephone_count_update es el mismo de cursor_telephone_count.

```
CURSOR cursor_telephone_count IS 
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     INTO ln_telephone_count 
     FROM TELEPHONE t 
     WHERE t.telephone_number = :NEW.telephone_number 
     AND t.identity_code= :NEW.identity_code 
     AND t.customer_id = :NEW.customer_id;
```

la razon de separarlos fue para validar si el query debia ser diferente en update, reemplaze los NEW por OLD pero no funciono.

Comment: Habría que ver los datos de prueba, porque no sabemos si es que está entrando en el caso en el que los datos que comparas en el IF de UPDATING no cambian

Comment: Estaba mirando y me di cuenta que cualquier asignación que ponga debajo de mi "FETCH cursor_telephone_count INTO ln_telephone_count;" no lo toma si es una actualizacion, cosa que si toma si es insert, es decir yo debajo de hay pongo :NEW.line_state := 'INVALID'; , lo que invalidaria cualquie insert, y lo toma en los insert, pero con update es como si el fecth no deja que pase.

Comment: ¿Estás consciente que consultas la misma tabla que modificas?

Comment: Revisa [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93011/trigger-y-tabla-mutante). ¿Tienes otros disparadores o algún `WHEN others` que se trague un ORA-04091?

Comment: @Sal , muchas gracias , efectivamente el problema era por mutación en la tabla, soy nuevo en manejar disparadores en Oracle y no conocía ese detalle, muchas gracias.